# Show an orthonormal basis is a set of eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, orthonormal

Consider the orthonormal basis $B= \{ {\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w} \}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the transformation $T:
\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by

$$T({\bf x}) = {\bf x} - 2 ({\bf x} \cdot {\bf u}) {\bf u} .$$

Show that $B$ is a set of eigenvectors for $T$ and find the eigenvalues corresponding to the eigenvectors ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$.
Describe $T$ geometrically.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried finding the representative matrix of T, but it hasn't led me anywhere.

Comment: Try putting in ${\bf u} = {\bf x}$ in your transformation and see what you get for $T({\bf u})$.  Then repeat with ${\bf v} = {\bf x}$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$T({\bf u}) = {\bf u} - 2 ({\bf u} \cdot {\bf u}) {\bf u} = - {\bf u}$$

This is an eigenvalue equation with eigenvalue $\lambda = -1$.

Now plug in to find $T({\bf v})$ and use your knowledge of orthogonality.

Can you continue?

As for geometry:  Note what $T$ does to each eigenvector.  Imagine what it does to points on a sphere.  Think about inversions...

Comment: Thank you for the help!